# Firefox 3.6 <label><p> rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a label containing a `<p>` tag in my html code. but firefox 3.6 is rendering the `<p>` tag outside the label which is breaking the html. all other browsers including different FF versions are rendering it just fine. please help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML specification does not allow `<p>` elements inside `<label>` elements. When you write [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML, expect browsers to error recover in different and unwanted ways.

```
<!ELEMENT LABEL - - (%inline;)* -(LABEL) -- form field label text -->
```

"A label element can contain any number of things that are 'inline' except other labels"

```
<!ENTITY % inline "#PCDATA | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %special; | %formctrl;">
```

"Inline consists of text, things that are considered 'fontstyle', 'phrase', etc"

If you [follow the links through](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), you won't find `p` in any of those groups.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting block-element inside inline-element is not legal...

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simply because p tags cannot be nested within a label tag. It's not valid markup. I suggest you check your work in a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the following css rules:

```
p {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

This will make the `<p>` tag an inline level element.

Comment: That is one of the worst answers I have ever seen. HTML is a language with a syntax. It has to follow a set of rules the same as anything else. Forcing the element to behave differently using css is a hack and should be avoided.

Comment: @James - You can't use CSS to make a element *behave* differently. You can make elements *display* differently, and that's all CSS ever does. This is a bad answer not because it's a hack, but because it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, it might be illegal and should be avoided but it _does_ work. When you want something to work, sometimes you don't care if it is wrong or not.

Comment: @cenanozen: This won't fix the underlying problem in Firefox 3.6. The DOM will still be "broken" compared to other browsers such as Chrome.

Comment: Browsers render HTML elements based on their own internal stylesheets -- cenanozen's answer is ugly because it makes the HTML markup extremely confusing (defeating the semantic meanings), but it does work.